# Check what user typed in filter column in radgridview

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I have a radGridView in a form; can i check what user selected as filter? (ex: Contains, Does not contain, Starts with, etc..) 
And if a filter is selected, what it was typed there?

Example:

[image]

I have one column called 'Title' and there i have Contain filter selected and in that filter i typed "TEST".
Can i somehow get all those information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
The radgridview has this 'FilterDescriptors' property that saves everything you type in every filter field and also the 'PropertyName' which gives you the column.

So you can basically do this:

```
foreach (var descriptor in this.FilterDescriptors)
{
     foreach (var column in this.MasterTemplate.Columns)
     {
          if (descriptor.PropertyName == column.FieldName)
          {
               //do stuff
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I assume that selection of filters is made with checkboxes and filter text with textbox.

Textbox has event `TextChanged` or `KeyPress`, which is fired when user type some text.

In this event you can check checked state of filter selection.

Example:

```
private void textBox_search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string query = textBox_search.Text;

      if(checkbox_contains.Checked)
      {  
          //your filter logic
      }
      else if(checkbox_startsWith.Checked)
      {
          //your filter logic
      }

      //rest
}
```

Comment: No, i don't use checkboxes or textboxes.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see that you mentioning radGridView.

Comment: No problem! Thank you for the answer!